# ...に間違い言わない - Meaning and grammar

Tags: grammar, expressions

I can't understand very well the meaning and the grammar in this sentence:

> 田中さんの言葉に間違い言わない！

Is possibile that the its meaning is something like "Tanaka-san is always right?"

Comment: Where is this "sentence" from?  Are you sure it says 間違い言わない?

Comment: No, not at all. I head this sentence here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KRGbt1B_xiE&t=57s

The character talks about "Chariot", but, to simplify matters, I modified it with "Tanaka-san".

Comment: I think it's `間違いはない`。

Comment: Mmh, indeed it can be so!
So the sentence, literally, can be translated as "In X's words, there aren't errors". Right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The character says:

> 「シャリオの言葉{ことば}に間違{まちが}い**は**ない！」

and not 「間違い言わない」.  (「言葉**に**間違い言わない」 is ungrammatical, hence my comment above.)

The sentence means:

> "Chariot's words are accurate."